# Self-referencing zero or one to many (0-1 -> N) relation in Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many, self-referencing-table, ef-core-6.0

I have this simple entity which may have some children of its own type:

```
public class File {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public File? Parent { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }

    public IList<File>? Children { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Actually, an individual entity may has a parent of its own type or not; and it may be parent for some other entities of its own type (`0-1 -> N` relationship). I've tried to configure it in Entity Framework Core 6 with these lines of code:

```
// Didn't work:
builder.HasOne(t => t.Parent).WithMany(t => t.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ParentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Actually I've tried all combinations of `HasForeignKey`, `HasPrincipalKey`, `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`, `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`, and `DeleteBehavior.NoAction` with that, but all I got was this:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_File_File_ParentId' on table
> 'File' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE
> NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
> constraints.

Can anyone help me please?

NOTE: I haven't any other relations on this entity. Actually this is the only entity I ever have in this domain.

**UPDATE:** It's pretty weird! Looking at the generated SQL seems too odd:

```
CREATE TABLE [File] (
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ParentId] bigint NULL,
    [Name] varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_File] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_File_File_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId])
        REFERENCES [File] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

It seems EF is ignoring the `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior...)` command, and it's creating `ON DELETE CASCADE` part in all cases!

Comment: Do you have any other `.OnDelete` relationships to this table?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman No I don't have any. And this is the only entity I ever have in this domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a cyclic relationship, and your database cannot create a foreign key constraint with a delete cascade for such relationships (as the error message indicates).

I suspect that your current migration still has `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` enabled which causes the error on applying the migration. Everytime you change the `DeleteBehavior`, you need to update your migration (remove the old one, and (re)create a new one).

Can you post the generated migration code?

Comment: Yep! That was the exact problem. I wasn't coding for a few years, and it seems I've to re-learn too many things ::))) Thanks.